# I get Error in installing tidyverse package

Tags: r, error-handling, installation, tidyverse, ggpairs

I tried different ways to install `tidyverse` package, but it shows this error

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
>    namespace ‘vctrs’ 0.2.0 is already loaded, but >= 0.2.1 is required

I'm trying to run `ggpairs` and I get this error at the end.

> Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
>     namespace ‘vctrs’ 0.2.0 is being loaded, but >= 0.2.1 is required

Is there something related with the version?

Comment: Things to try: 1) Update all your packages. 2) With RStudio closed try installing vctrs from R.

Comment: Could you please share the installation script of 'vctrs' via basic r console?

Comment: Run ```install.packages("vctrs")```

Comment: Thank you it worked and the error got solved